# What XPath query will select the <Duration: 29 hrs > node in the following XML?

Tags: selenium, xpath

The following line of code are as follows in which i have to find xpath query for

```
</div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 "> 
 <div class="panel panel-white"> 
 <div class="pl-10 pr-10 pt-10 pb-10">
 <p>
 <b class="attribute">Duration: </b> 29 hrs </p>
 <p>
 <b class="attribute">Difficulty:</b> Intermediate </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//b[contains(., 'Duration:')]/parent::p
```

More information you get [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below XPath

```
//div[@class='pl-10 pr-10 pt-10 pb-10']/p/b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following x-path, `//p[b[starts-with(.,'Duration:')]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **XPATH** :

```
//div[contains(@class,'panel-white')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::b[contains(text(),'Duration:')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - //p[b[starts-with(text(),'Duration')]]